# linux/xfce4: How to get rid of "choose session name"?

Tags: linux, login, session

I've been running `xcfe4` for a long time with no problems under linux.

Today I was making some changes to grub and doing some reboots to test it. Now, every time I enter my login password via the `lightdm` login screen, `xfce4` pops up a dialog which prompts me to choose between logging out or entering a new session name. I have to either double-click on `Default` or enter some random text as the session name in order to get past this screen.

This never used to happen before. I'm guessing that one of my recent reboots left my `xfce4` session in some sort of incomplete state, and now I am always given this dialog upon logging in after shutdown or reboot.

This even occcurs if I do a normal logout from `xfce4` without a shutdown or reboot.

I didn't change anything in my settings, neither concerning logins or sessions, nor anything else.

Does anyone know how to disable this popup, so that once again I simply get my standard xfce4 session after login?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it: I had to go to `Settings->Settings Editor->xfce4-session`. The `chooser` attribute had `AlwaysDisplay` checked. I unchecked it and exited from `Settings`. Then, after shutdown, reboot, and logout, I am no longer prompted for a session.

I have no idea how that setting changed from its earlier value. But anyway, all's well that ends well.